# Is there a removable, pole or essential singularity for the following function

Tags: complex-analysis

Given this function $f(z) = \frac{e^z}{z^2}$

I need to determine whether there is a pole, or it is removable or it has the essential singularity.

My Approach:
I know that $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{inf}\frac{z^n}{n!}$ in power series expansion, but I cannot seem to find any removable due to lowest term is 1 from the power series expansion.

Now the question is in this case, does this mean there is a pole at 0 with order of 2, or does it have an essential singularity which implies that both pole and removable cannot happen in the following function.

Comment: Have you considered $\lim_{z\to 0} z^2 f(z)$?

Comment: @DavidPeterson, you mean using f(z) =$a_{n}(z - z_{0})^n$ formula?

Comment: Also I am supposed to use the power series expansion...

Comment: $\frac{1}{f(z)}=z^2e^{-z}$, which is analytic and has a zero of order two at $z=0$. Therefore, $f$ has a pole of order $2$  at $z=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$f(z)=\frac 1 {z^{2}}+ \frac 1 z+\frac  1 {2!}+\frac  z {3!}+\cdots$ so $f$ has  a pole of order $2$ at $0$.